# jQuery not firing on dynamically generated content

Tags: jquery, each, dynamic-content

I got an article list with an "expand" in it. I'm firing the expand with this code:

```
var collapsedSize = '50px';
$('.page-press .article-text-wrapper').each(function() {
    console.log("yes");
    var _this = $(this);
    var _thisLink = $(this).find(".article-icon-showmore");
    var h = this.scrollHeight;
    _thisLink.on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(this).hasClass("showless")) {
            _this.find(".article-text").css('height', collapsedSize);
            $(this).text("mehr anzeigen").removeClass("showless");
        } else {
            _this.find(".article-text").css('height', h);
            $(this).text("weniger anzeigen").addClass("showless");
        }   
    });
});
```

But I'm loading more content for the article list via ajax call and fill an html template and append it into the parent div.

The code above doesn't work on the newly generated content. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is you are binding the click event only to the elements that are in the DOM when the page loads.  If you instead bind the click event to the document and provide a selector it will also work for elements added after the JavaScript runs.

Here is how I think it should work:

```
    var collapsedSize = '50px';
    $(document).on('click', '.page-press .article-text-wrapper .article-icon-showmore', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $articleTextWrapper = $(this).parents('.article-text-wrapper');
        if ($(this).hasClass("showless")) {
            $articleTextWrapper.find(".article-text").css('height', collapsedSize);
            $(this).text("mehr anzeigen").removeClass("showless");
        } else {
            $articleTextWrapper.find(".article-text").css('height', $articleTextWrapper[0].scrollHeight);
            $(this).text("weniger anzeigen").addClass("showless");
        }
    });
```

Without the HTML I can't test this JavaScript, but the concept of binding the click event to the document should work.

Comment: Perfect. I will check that out and let you know!

Comment: it worked like a charm. Thank you. Will def. learn from that!